# Components styles shouldn't depend on the rest of the app?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, web-component

In Angular 2 there's something I'm still not quite getting. Usually a component is described as:

> A reusable building block for an application

And it is made up of HTML/CSS/Javascript. What confuses me here is the styling.

Now what actualy makes me worried here is the styling. The reason this makes me worried is because concerning the DOM, the styles of one element are usually affected by those available to the parent.

In that sense, depending on where we put the component, a different effect might be caused upon it by the parents' styles which might make it not really reusable, since it might look great when we build it inside a certain situation, but might break completely somewhere else.

Furthermore, there may be other classes available "globally" in some sense and I've already seem being used inside some components. The major example here is Bootstrap.

I've seem people using Bootstrap's classes like `row`, `form-control` and whatever. Those classes are "outside" of the component, they are made available to the app, and the component is "relying on faith" that the classes will be available. In that sense the component is relying in something from outside of itself, which I don't know how interferes with this "reusable building block".

In that sense, styling has these two issues (there may be more, actually) - the influence from parents and the possibility of using global styles like Bootstrap.

How should we deal with this? How do we solve this issue to make a good component design?

A component shouldn't really rely on something external like Bootstrap? If so, what is the correct way to deal with these styling issues?

Comment: For something like bootstrap, you can just put the reference in your index.html and you can guarantee that it is available on all of your components.

Answer (score 0):

To address your first point, a component's styles aren't inherited by its children in the same way as normal css. The Shadow Dom makes you have to be explicit about allowing inheritance, such as the pierce operator `.parent >>> .child: {...}`, or /deep/ `.parent /deep/ .child: {...}`. So each component's styles are completely isolated by default.

As for global styling and widgets from 3rd party libraries, if you've got more than can be easily managed (ie. more than 1), you could wrap the styles with your own semantic classes.

eg.

```
.my-button-appearance {
  @extend .waves-effect;
  @extend .btn-flat;
  color: color('orange', 'lighten-2');
}
```